# typescript / es6 + browserify + babelify: export not visible

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I'm trying to develop a library written in Typescript and transpiled into a standalone es5 bundle. It works if I use only one single .ts. Otheriwse it doesn't.

Below is an example of what doesn't work.

**src/A.ts**

```
export function fun1() {
    return "fun1";
}
```

**src/B.ts**

```
export function fun2() {
    return "fun2";
}
```

**e2e/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="lib.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log("fun1: " + pizza.fun1());
    console.log("fun2: " + pizza.fun2());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
"build-js": "tsc ./src/**.ts -t es6 --outDir ./dist/es6/ && browserify -d --s pizza -t babelify ./dist/es6/**.js -o ./dist/lib.js"
```

**generated lib.js**

```
(function(f){if(typeof exports...
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.fun1 = fun1;

function fun1() {
    return "fun1";
}

},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.fun2 = fun2;

function fun2() {
    return "fun2";
}

},{}]},{},[1,2])(2)
});
```

The error message I'm getting is: `Uncaught TypeError: pizza.fun1 is not a function` and only `fun2` is visible in the `pizza` object.

1. Any idea why fun1 is not visible and how to make it visible?
2. The proposed solution should also work later on with Typescript `export class blah`

Comment: One solution I don't necessary like so much is to create a Facade object which exposes the api. e.g. `export class Facade {public fun() {return fun1() + fun2();}`

Comment: whay use babel at all  and not just use tsify ?